# db.QueryContext(ctx, query, args) is making new connection for same db variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go

I am using a variable `"db *sql.DB"` on which I have defined 2 methods `A()` and `B()`. `B()` is called inside `A()` with same `"db"` variable used to call `A()`.
(--CHECK CODE--)
Now the `db.ExecContext()` func is creating a new DB connection in `B()` even though the same variable is passed into `B()`.
It should have used same connection made in its call in `A()`.
Please tell a solution..

```
type caller struct{
    db *sql.DB
}
func (caller) A(){
    db.ExecContext()
    db.B()
}

func (caller) B(){
    db.ExecContext()
}
```

Comment: Your example code and your question are out of sync because Go does not allow declaring methods on imported types, so the code you are showing can *not* possibly compile nor run, and therefore cannot possibly create any kind of connection to anything.

Comment: sql.DB represents a connection pool. It's not surprising at all that the exec methods create new connections. Use transactions if you want to guarantee that queries execute on the same connection.

Comment: I had written it wrongly but now I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

So what was happening is I was doing

```
A(){
    rows, _ := db.ExecContext()
    defer rows.close()

    for rows.Next(){

        B()

    }
}
```

So this B() was called before the defer could close  that previous connection made by "ExecContext" and started making new connections.
I had to call B() in a separate loop after all the rows are fetched.